# python: parse owl file in manchester syntax to owlready

Tags: python, owl, rdflib, owlready, manchester-syntax

Is it possible to parse an ontology given in manchester syntax such that it ends up as an [owlready](https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) ontology-object.

This is what I found out so far:

- Owlready itself can only import "NTriples, RDF/XML or OWL/XML format" ([ref1](https://bitbucket.org/jibalamy/owlready2/src/master/README.rst)).
- [Ontospy](https://lambdamusic.github.io/Ontospy/) can (among other things) convert between these formats: `['xml', 'turtle', 'n3', 'nt', 'trix', 'rdfa']` ([ref2](https://github.com/lambdamusic/Ontospy/blob/master/ontospy/core/rdf_loader.py#L34)).
- [rdflib](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io) has a function [`rdflib.extras.infixowl.manchesterSyntax(...)`](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apidocs/rdflib.extras.html#rdflib.extras.infixowl.manchesterSyntax) but which seems not to be documented very well and seems not to be applicable to a whole file (or `str` with several statements).

Is there any othter project I am missing, or is there an easy way to combine (someOf) these projects to parse an owl file in manchester syntax to an owlready ontology?

Comment: the method in `rdflib` is for serialization, not for parsing. You can simply use Python code to create ontology objects in a DSL like in `owlready`. Long story short, if you don't find a parser then it doesn't work. So you would have to use some external API like the OWL API. You could also make use of a REST service, see http://mowl-power.cs.man.ac.uk:8080/converter/restful.jsp or https://www.ldf.fi/service/owl-converter/ - clearly, you could call this from Python as well, just would have to write the output to disk and then you could point `owlready` to the new file

Comment: @UninformedUser Are you sure that the link [ref2](https://github.com/lambdamusic/Ontospy/blob/master/ontospy/core/rdf_loader.py#L34) refers to serialization and not to parsing? Because the module and the class are named "loader"(?). Anyway, using an REST service is a good idea. Nevertheless, I would prefer have a local solution. While the best would be "Python only" to minimize complexity, I guess that is currently not possible. Do you know how much effort it is to call OWL-API from the command line to convert between Manchester syntax  and say RDF/XML?

Comment: I'm confused now. I was referring to the `rdflib` method you mentioned - and this is just for serialization. Your link [ref2](https://github.com/lambdamusic/Ontospy/blob/master/ontospy/core/rdf_loader.py#L34) is for `ontospy` but this hasn't support for Manchester Syntax

Comment: this API should work form CLI: https://github.com/sszuev/ont-converter

Comment: The translation from Manchester syntax to OWL 2 Functional-Style Syntax (and likewise XML-style syntax) is mostly straightforward; see here: https://www.w3.org/2007/OWL/wiki/ManchesterSyntax#Informal_Description. You could use a simple library such as [pyparsing](https://pypi.org/project/pyparsing/) and implement it yourself, perhaps only for the relevant subset of OWL.